# How to prevent inconsistent data when using @future methods in triggers?

Tags: apex, future, transaction

Due to certain governor limits in my trigger I refactored it to work asynchronously with @future:

```
public with sharing class CustomObject_TriggerHandler {

  public static void afterInsert(Map<Id, CustomObject__c> newObjects){
      processAsynchronously(newObjects.keySet());
  }

 @future
 private static void processAsynchronously(Set<Id> newObjectIds) {
      ...
```

What happens if it takes 5min for the future method to run and a user in the meanwhile changes any data that my trigger code touches or modifies?

**Can I corrupt my data consistency or does the platform provide means to prevent this. Either automatically or by using some transaction extensions in my code?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asynchronous by definition gives the notion of a queue so will be processes only when resources are available.

I wonder if this is exactly why salesforce only let's you pass only native values as parameters rather than object instances. In this way it makes you query any data that you might be modifying rather than trying to update a previously cached instance. So whilst there will be no data corruption, it is a realistic possibility that in a busy org with a lot of future calls backing up, you may end up overwriting something that the user modified in the interim.

So that should be factored into your call design, only defer operations to future which don't need to be performed instantly for the system to be on a consistent state. Only defer that which can wait.

Comment: Sounds great. Does this mean Salesforce.com or the general database concepts of queues and transactions prevents dirty reads/updates and other data inconsistencies?

Comment: Yes absolutely, if you have a record open in edit mode, and someone else / integration user updates it in the background, when you try to save it, it will give you an error saying someone else already updated it. 'Optimistic locking'

Comment: techtrecker: What does that mean in my trigger context? As the trigger is asynch now no error message will be presented to the user on "Save". What happens when something in the future transaction fails?

Comment: If a user was editing a record that your trigger updated in the background, they would receive an error.

Comment: Keep in mind also that such errors are not shown if an Batch Apex job or future job updates records "as" the user. And the user themselves was the record open in another tab in Edit. When they hit save, it will overwrite any changes the batch / future job made.

Comment: @RobertS If the changes that user made would cause your trigger to fire, then another instance of your trigger would be instantiated. The important thing to know from the APEX documentation is this: "Methods with the future annotation cannot take sObjects or objects as arguments." I'd take that to mean that if they committed changes to a record that caused the trigger to fire again, their changes to the data should likely be safe.